# Phrase Frequency formula for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, frequency, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of search terms and would like to find out all the two-word phrases in this column and the frequency of each of all them. Does anyone know of a formula in Google Sheets that can help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY(IF(SPLIT(A1:A, " ")>0, A1:A, ),
 "select Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
    and Col3='' 
  group by Col2 
  label count(Col2)'frequency'"),
 QUERY(IF(SPLIT(A1:A, " ")>0, A1:A, ),
 "select Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2
  label count(Col2)'frequency'")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the formula, it close to what I'm looking for. I need something that automatically tell how many times phrases are in the cells themselves. Here is a example how in depth I want it to go.

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK0J0.png

Answer (score 0):

pste in **C2** and drag down:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A:A, SEARCH("*"&B2&"*", A:A)))
```

[image: 3]